# Google Drive API Credential token Clear from Local Computer

Tags: c#, winforms, google-drive-api

i am using google drive API v3 to upload file directly to google drive . when i execute program it's work properly in 1st time with Client Secret and Client ID ,problem happens when i change  Client Secret and Client ID in Same Computer problem occur . it's seems like previous Client Secret and Client ID saved in Computer create some problem .

Comment: Not sure I understood correctly but as per my understanding just right click on secret file in solution explorer and change copy to output directory option to copy if newer or copy always. It will update your secret file in output directory whenever its updated

Comment: Are you changing the Client Secret/Client ID, how exactly are you doing this? Please add some more details and reproduction steps as this works for me.